What kind of spider is this (Colorado)?
I need help identifying what kind of spider this could be. Thanks.


From the leg and body proportions, and the two-tone colouring of the abdomen vs cephalothorax, this is most likely in the Trachelidae family of Broad-faced Sac Spiders.
The Woodlouse Hunter spider (Dysdera crocata) has similar colouring, but the body proportions and, in particular, the chelicerae (mouth parts) are significantly different.
From the Trachelidae family, North America gets the genera Trachelas and Meriola. See https://bugguide.net/node/view/1017586 for additional details.
